How to list 3d party Amazon Marketplace instances with AWS CLI?
The EC2 -> Instances -> Reserved Instances shows some 3d party instances available for purchase: 
How can this list be obtained with the AWS CLI?
I've tried:
aws ec2 describe-reserved-instances-offerings --availability-zone us-east-1e --include-marketplace --filters Name=marketplace,Values=true > output.txt

But it sometimes returns 125MB worth of data (with hundreds of m5a.large instances while the UI only shows a handful), other times it only returns 5KB with 5 instances total.
What's the proper command to use to obtain a correct list of 3d party instances?
